# File/Folder Structure in Team Foundation Service

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

When adding projects to TFS, I'll add a project for a specific website.  This works fine, and all the folders and files within the root of the website are available in TFS.  However, there are also shared files that are above the root of the website, and are not included in the specific website project/solution, since they reside outside the root of the website.    For example, when I add existing files to a project, that are outside the root, it creates duplicates within the project.  Or, when adding existing file to the project, it creates the wrong folder hierarchy in the project (appears as though the folder above the root is inside the website), which will result in problems with publishing and sharing source in TFS.

What is the appropriate way to include these files in the project, so that the files can remain outside the root, but be included in the project in TFS.

Comment: Hi, it might be useful if you could add a tree diagram that shows how your folders are layed out, and how you want them to be layed out.

Comment: The folder structure is not complex.  Its a web root, containing the website, and then one level above the root has a folder for common files.  That is how I need them to be.

Answer (score 1):

One way you might achieve this is by simply having **one Team Project for all your websites**, and logically break it up into different sites for backlogs/iterations/work items etc by using teams/areas.  All your source code will be within the correct hierarchical structure within your one Team Project, and can then be shared between the subprojects within the Team Project.

See the following posts for a discussion of this approach:

- [Project of Projects with team Foundation Server 2010](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/project-of-projects-with-team-foundation-server-2010/)
- [When should I use Areas in TFS instead of Team Projects in Team Foundation Server 2010](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/when-should-i-use-areas-in-tfs-instead-of-team-projects-in-team-foundation-server-2010/)
- [One Team Project](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/one-team-project/)

Comment: Thanks, ngm.  I had read a couple of those prior.  The issue I have is that code is added to Team Foundation Service with the folder/file structure of the project in VS, but the project in VS has a root of the website, without access to the shared common files.  And, the publishing process from VS maps the local project folder/file structure to the dev/prod server folder structure.  What's confusing is how to structure the project in VS, so that it moves the source code to project in TFS, including the common files, and retains the folder structure to match dev/prod for publishing. Make sense?

Comment: I was also considering adding another project with the common files, but this makes it harder to work with the files together, and publish at the same time, etc.